# How to add Vagrant box and Virtual box machine (which is not installed via vagrant) to the same NAT network?

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox

I have a kali linux vagrant box installed, and I want it to connect to the same NAT Network with my vuln.hub lab (which is not installed via vagrant, just imported to VirtualBox). Apparently I do not see option for making NAT-Network mode enabled.

I tried the following but It won't work :/

```
config.vm.network:natnetwork "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.10"
```

Sorry If It is some basic question, just figuring the way for 3hours. And my default created NAT is isolated from vuln.hub

Thanks in advance guys!